# the javascript execute not work how to change it?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//window.onload = Now;
function Now(){
var n=new Date();
return n.toLocaleDateString();

};


</script>
```

i put the above code in the head part.

```
<body onload="Now();">
```

but on the page, there is no show anything.when i using **window.onload = Now** or put the script code after the  label; the result is the same, why?

ps:i want to write the result out on the page. but when i used document.write(Now()); it still not displayed on the page.

Comment: The `Now` function doesn't do anything, except return a value. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: What result? What do you expect this code to do? As far as I can see it works out what the time is then throws away the result.

Comment: You haven't written the code to display it on the browser

Comment: i want to write the result out on the page. thank you.

Comment: try this . `document.write(Now())` or `alert(Now())`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the return value of `Now()`, so it is being quietly discarded.

Perhaps you want to do something like `onload="alert(Now());"`

Comment: i want to write the result out. but when i used document.write(Now()); it still not work.

Comment: That's because `document.write` can only be called before the page has loaded.

Comment: if i want to show the result on the page? how do i do? thank you.

Comment: There are many ways. The most primitive being `document.body.innerHTML = something`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put alert box. If it exists in the script or not.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your HTML a bit to have a DOM element that will help you post the resut onto your page,

```
<body onload="Now();">
    <span id="dateHelper"></span>
</body>
```

And then modify your script to do the following,

```
function Now(){
    var n=new Date();
    var lds = n.toLocaleDateString();

    document.getElementById("dateHelper").innerHTML = lds;
};
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/wThaz/)